# python distutils simple example - how are parameters parsed

Tags: python

Referring to [**A Simple Example** from python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/introduction.html#a-simple-example):

This is `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='foo',
      version='1.0',
      py_modules=['foo'],
      )
```

And then it says to run this command:

`python setup.py sdist`

How/what/where is the parameter `sdist` being parsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setup` function parses the command line arguments: it reads `sys.argv`. See [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/core.py).

You're certainly confusing between function arguments (the ones defined in the `setup.py` script) and the command line arguments: (which are `setup.py sdist`).

A piece of information is given in the `run_setup` function comment:

> 'sys.argv[0]' will be replaced with 'script' for the duration of the call.  'script_args' is a list of strings; if supplied,
>
> 'sys.argv[1:]' will be replaced by 'script_args' for the duration of the call.